# Create tf.estimator.Estimator from tf.saved_model.SavedModel

Tags: python, tensorflow, tensorflow-estimator

I have a TensorFlow model on disk saved using tf.saved_model.builder.SavedModelBuilder. How to create a TF Estimator from it?